# How to update view after clearCoreDataStore()?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button that calls clearCoreDataStore(). However, after it gets executed the view does not update, it still shows content. How can I update that?

On a related note, how can I update the view **after** I got data inserted to the app's Core Data stack?

I have the following 'fetching' code outside the class declaration:

```
fileprivate var fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity: 
NSFetchedResultsController<Map> = {
// Create Fetch Request
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Map> = Map.fetchRequest()

// Configure Fetch Request
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

// Create Fetched Results Controller
let fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity = 
NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity
}()

fileprivate var fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity: NSFetchedResultsController<Coordinate> = {
// Create Fetch Request
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Coordinate> = Coordinate.fetchRequest()

// Configure Fetch Request
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "latitude", ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "longitude", ascending: true)]

// Create Fetched Results Controller
let fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity
}()
```

and on viewDidLoad, I do:

```
do {
        try fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity.performFetch()
        try fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity.performFetch()
} catch
```

Comment: have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate) delegate

Comment: But I already have NSFetchedResultsController implemented?

Comment: you can use notification or delegate for this